# Powershell: rename-item increment if exist (multiple extensions)

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with files having multiple extensions and I need to rename them to "thisname".
Renaming should happen like the following

```
test.txt   -> thisname.txt  
test1.txt  -> thisname1.txt  
bascic.vbs -> thisname.vbs  
basic1.vbs -> thisname1.vbs
```

The following is what I have tried so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $subfolder_path\*.* -exclude *.jpg, *.pdf |
    rename-item -newname { -join($jxl) + $_.extension }
```

This part of code rename only one one file i need to make increment on all duplicity extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I fully understood your needs but give this a try

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $subfolder_path\*.* -Exclude *.jpg, *.pdf |
    Rename-Item -NewName {
        $newName = "thisname" + $_.Extension
        for($i = 0; Test-Path $newName; ++$i) {
            $newName = "thisname" + $i + $_.Extension
        }
        $newName
    }
```

If this does not help you please share some more information about the desired behaviour

Comment: Clever use of the exit condition of the `for` loop :)

Comment: Not enough, this rename still only first file on second i got error:

Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At D:\script\filter.ps1:44 char:16
+     Rename-Item <<<<  -NewName {
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\script\test\1\readme_first.txt:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: Then please share more information about your environment and script. Your error shows that it appears in a script at line 44. I also tested it with a folder structure of just the 4 files you mentioned in your question and there the script worked so there clearly must be something we currently don't know about your context.

Comment: Hello DAX, thanks for your quick response. Im using PS v1.0. I added only this few lines to new .ps1 it work fine with first file but at another throw the error that ive mentioned above.

Comment: Im sorry its 2.0

Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : ccf7ed8a-9774-4b1e-832c-aefc764f1b45
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHo
CurrentCulture   : sk-SK
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

Answer (score 0):

Need to set location first.

```
Set-Location -Path <path to files>
```

After this everything goes right.